# Writing a file not performed when writing task is handled in onLocationChanged()

Tags: android, locationmanager, fileoutputstream

I am trying to write the `latitude` and `longitude` formed by the location manager to a file but the write operation doesn't work for some reason. The following is the code I have been trying with.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        File absPath = getFilesDir();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                String filename = "myfile";
                FileOutputStream outputStream;
                try {
                    outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    outputStream.write((location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude()).getBytes());
                    outputStream.close();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }

        };
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
   }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Try `outputStream.flush()` after `outputStream.write()`.

Comment: @Boss 1)Tried it.. No luck..  
2)My bad, was trying to edit some thing before copying the code here. However my code contains `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates`.  I edited it. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Do you have anything on the logcat? Are you sure your `onLocationChanged()` is getting called?

Comment: Yup I tried `Toast` and it displays the lat and long. And No errors in log cat.

Comment: At which location did you checked for this file?

Comment: I checked in the root, Android folder and  data folder..

Comment: How and with what did you check if the file existed? It is certainly not in the root or in the Android folder. And you cannot look in the /data folder by other means. Have you tried to read the file? If so then show your code. If not then start coding.

Comment: @greenapps Yup, I found out the path it is storing using Toast. Its storing in `data/data/com.example.myapp`.. And I am  successfully able to read back the data from that location. But interestingly `data/data` is invisible. I got to figure out how to access that or I need to manually give a location which I can access to store the files.

Comment: `data/data/com.example.myapp`. No it is `/data/data/com.example.myapp` or yet better `/data/data/com.example.myapp/files`. It is normal that `/data` is visible and `/data/data` not. You cannot look in the `/data` directory.

Comment: So if I wanna store something in `/Android/data/com.example.myapp` in my internal storage, Am I supposed to give the path manually or is their any other way?

Comment: That path does not exist. It could be '/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.myapp' though. But you don't have to code that path manually or fixed. That is a bad idea. Use getExternalFilesDir(). What you want is named external memory. Although it is build in in the device. Don't forget to request read/write external storage permisssion in manifest file. Then after that use 'new FileOutputStrem()' and 'new FileInputStream()' to write and read from files. Supply full path to those classes.

Comment: True. So now I got a clear picture. Though my phone says Internal Storage , it's not actual internal storage that android assumes. I got it worked as you said using `getExternalFilesDir()`.. @greenapps